# Please identify this African violet

Tags: african-violets

This plant has 5 leaflets that are pink/lavender with darker edged[image]

Answer (score 2):

African violets, commonly sold as houseplants, are native African species of the Genus **Saintpaulia**. These plants have long been selected by breeders to enhance certain floral traits that are attractive to collectors (i.e. color variants, frilly colored edged petals, double or single flowers etc.). According to Wikipedia, your plant is probably a house plant **cultivar** and probably derived solely from **Saintpaulia ionantha**. However, more recent breeding has also utilized other species of Saintpaulia, so it may be a mixed hybrid **variety**. The referenced Wikipedia article at the link below may have additional information that might be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saintpaulia